# Selenium (Java) Get FULL text from shortened displayed on page

Tags: java, selenium, gettext

I want to get the FULL text of link, that is contained in a page element and retrieve is value possibly with `.getText()` parameter. Problem is, that on the page there is only part of it displayed followed by "...".

```
.getText returns = "http://www.example.com/es_es/spa..."
what I need to get ="http://www.example.com/es_es/spain/legal-notice.html"
```

this is HTML

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com/es_es/spain/legal-notice.html" 

target="_blank">http://www.example.com/es_es/spa...</a>
```

I am able to locate the element, just not to retrieve its full text. I tried `.getAttribute("href")` but it `returns "null"`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using xpath :

```
WebElement hrefText=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='http://www.example.com/es_es/spain/legal-notice.html']"));
String text_hrefText=hrefText.getAttribute("href");
System.out.println(text_hrefText);
```

Comment: Glad it helps u

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to use **`getText()`** method, but **`getText()`** will be helpfull while we want to retrieve the **`innerHTML`** only. But if we use **`getAttribute()`** method, we will be able to pull out any of the **`attributes`** of the **`WebElement`**.

Now, to retrieve the full text of `href` attribute you can use the following line of code :

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'example.com/es_es/spain/legal-notice')]")).getAttribute("href"));
```